# cannot send email through php and postfix on VM

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I'm running LAMP on Ubuntu 11.04. I've installed postfix and configured php.ini file. I'm trying to send an email through php `mail()` function but it's not sending. When I check `mail.log` I get this error:

```
Jul 25 15:35:31 WINLSVR001 postfix/qmgr[7880]: fatal: dict_open: unsupported dictionary type: mysql:  Is the postfix-mysql package installed?
Jul 25 15:35:32 WINLSVR001 postfix/master[2547]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/qmgr pid 7880 exit status 1
Jul 25 15:35:32 WINLSVR001 postfix/master[2547]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/qmgr: bad command startup -- throttling
```

On tutorials, there is no mention of postfix-mysql package. Why do I need to set up this? Is this the problem?

Answer (score 1):

if you use any mysql lookups in postfix you need to install the [postfix-mysql](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty-updates/postfix-mysql) package. The default ubuntu postfix package doesn't include mysql maps.